# Xcode 12 throwing new C++ errors when compiling mapbox-gl-native

Tags: c++, xcode, mapbox-gl, mapbox-ios

I have always been able to compile a custom copy of `mapbox-gl-native`, but with the installation of Xcode 12 this has broken. I am getting the following errors:

**No matching function for call to 'get'**

[image]

[image]

**How can I fix this C++ error that is showing? I am assuming this is happening because of updated Xcode tools.**